# Accessing array elements within classes

Tags: php, json, class, object

When decoding one of my stored JSON strings the object's array members are encapsulated in objects, which makes it inconvenient to access the array elements.

The object `units` contains an array of `unit` objects defined by a key that is one of three types. The array is arranged like so:

`array (typeA => unit(1), typeB => unit(2), typeC => unit(3) )`

I also have an array that contains the three types in an order, like so:

`array (typeA, typeB, typeC)`

So to access a unit, given that you don't know the exact unit type, it would logically follow something like:

`Units->$type[$i][$j]`

But it doesn't work. I've tried the following:

`Units->{$type[$i]}[$j]`

`Units->$type[$i]->$j`

The only way I've managed to get it to work is by dividing the action into two lines. First getting the key and then applying the index for the unit object.

```
$aUnit = $units->$type[$i]; // Gets <type x>
$aUnit = $aUnit[$j]; // Gets the unit obj at j
```

Here's a dump of the structure:

```
object(stdClass)[4]
  public 'typeA' => 
    array (size=50)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'id' => int 436
```

Comment: `$users->{$type}[$i]` should work as expected. Do you have a full code example to look at?

Comment: Sorry I left out the additional array index, $j

Comment: Have you tried: `$units->{$type}[$i][$j]` ?

Comment: At least its working now!

Comment: I tried `$units->{$type[$i]}[$j]` and now it works, hm. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If @PhilCross have helped you, he should consider posting his comment as an answer and you accept it; I think the problem is not that simple (+1 from me) and for future reference it would be better for someone to find an answer without wading through comments :)